# How to get the TextField value when enter key is pressed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to pass `TextField` values when user press enter key from keyboard. In `onChange()` event, I am getting the value of the `textbox`, but How to get this value when `enter` key is pressed ?

Code:

```
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

class CartridgeShell extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value:''}
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <TextField 
             hintText="First Name" 
             floatingLabelText="First Name*"
             value={this.state.value} 
             onChange={this.handleChange} 
             fullWidth={true} />
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: where is your codes to show you tried?

Comment: It seems like mui prevents use of native browser functionality, forcing manual reimplementation using somewhat lower level code (manually checking keypresses). Am I missing something? (Honest question, I'm new to mui and trying to reorient my thinking.)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use `onKeyDown` event, and inside that check the key code of the key pressed by user. Key code of `Enter` key is 13, check the code and put the logic there.

Check this example:

```js
class CartridgeShell extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value:''}

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);
   } 
 
   handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
   }

   keyPress(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
         console.log('value', e.target.value);
         // put the login here
      }
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <input value={this.state.value} onKeyDown={this.keyPress} onChange={this.handleChange} fullWidth={true} />
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CartridgeShell/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id = 'app' />
```

**Note:** Replace the `input` element by Material-Ui `TextField` and define the other properties also.

Comment: [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated, maybe we should use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) instead ?

Comment: Use e.key === "Enter" instead

Answer (score 83):

Adding onKeyPress will work onChange in Text Field.

```
<TextField
  onKeyDown={(ev) => {
    console.log(`Pressed keyCode ${ev.key}`);
    if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
      // Do code here
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to get the value of the target TextField in the callback specified for `onKeyPress`.

Comment: how do you actually get the value of the TextFiled?

Comment: control the component and useState for value

Comment: `onKeyPress` happens before the field's value is actually set. Crap, i know. You can get the value of the textfield with the `onChange` prop... `onChange={ ev => console.log(ev.target.value) }`

Comment: @Neil, @PLO - `ev.target.value`

Comment: deprecated in mui

Comment: Shouldn't the `ev.preventDefault();` come before the `Do code here`?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `e.target.value` to get the current value of the `input` element if you're using [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) mode.

```
<TextField
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      alert(e.target.value);
    }
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This has nothing to do with `MUI v5`. This is regular DOM event which any version of the `TextField` component exposes to developers.

Comment: @vsync sorry for the confusion, I've updated this answer..

Comment: But why did you give an **exact** same answer (recently) when the same ones were given here years ago?

Comment: your demo isn't working

Answer (score 2):

```
<input onKeyPress={onKeyPress}/> 

const onKeyPress = (e: any) => { if (e.which == 13) { // your function }};
```

Answer (score 0):

`html`

```
<input id="something" onkeyup="key_up(this)" type="text">
```

`script`

```
function key_up(e){
    var enterKey = 13; //Key Code for Enter Key
    if (e.which == enterKey){
        //Do you work here
    }
}
```

Next time, Please try providing some code.

Comment: Please ask the OP for what they have tried before posting your own code.

Comment: why define `enterKey` and using memory when you can just write 13 in the `if`

Comment: @amirhoseinahmadi Nobody cares about memory these days as much as writing clean and understandable code. I have prettier in place in my project which does not let me use any magic numbers. It enforces to use a `const` instead, to define what number is about. I would prefer to see `enterKey` than just `13`

Comment: Next time, Please try providing some information about your code.