# going inside this method keyPress but I dont see any consoles printed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am trying to display the key entered value in the console. Right now I'm debugging. It's going inside the keyPress function, but I don't see any logs printed.

```
console.log("keyPress--->", e);
```

Can you tell me how to fix it so that in the future I will fix it myself.

I used this link as a reference: [How to get input textfield values when enter key is pressed in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384039/how-to-get-input-textfield-values-when-enter-key-is-pressed-in-react-js/43384732)

I am providing my code snippet and sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l20n739xqz). All my code is in `tab-demo.js`

```
 handleChangeText(e) {
    debugger;
    console.log("handleChangeText--->", e);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  keyPress(e) {
    debugger;
    console.log("keyPress--->", e);

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log("value", e.target.value);
      // put the login here
    }
```

Comment: I tried the provieded sandbox and it logs "keyPress---> 0" in the console properly.

Comment: @GlebKost hey thanks for your reply.... everytime it prints 0, eventhough if I press new character, can you tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You want to console log the input value, not the input itself.

```
console.log("keyPress--->", e.target.value);
```

Here's a dummy component called `App` which logs the input value as you wanted: https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/ebNGwr

Comment: hey I updated the code in sandbox but still not working...can you help me in updating sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/l20n739xqz

Comment: Can you please replicate what you have so far here: https://codepen.io/pen?template=ELRjGo

Comment: ReactJS is already hooked up so you just need to write your components in.

Comment: it would be great if you include in my sandbox since I have already all the components included there...please help codesandbox.io/s/l20n739xqz

Comment: I'm not too comfortable with sandbox unfortunately.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply..in my sandbox .... everytime it prints 0, eventhough if I press new character, can you tell me how to fix it...