# Material UI Input not detecting when enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI for my React project and unable to detect when the enter key has been pressed. I have tried the following which I thought should work but still unable to detect the event, not sure what I am missing.

I have a custom MUI component

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const handleChange = (event) => {
 setSearch(event.target.value);
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('enter key was pressed');
   }
 }

<SearchBox
  value={search}
  onChange={handleChange}
  placeholder="enter your search here"
  }}
/>
```

Comment: `onKeyDown` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384039/how-to-get-input-textfield-values-when-enter-key-is-pressed-in-react-js

Comment: Thank you, found answer in this thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Material UI Docs,
**onChange** event callback is only invoked if the field value is changed

Try using **onKeyPress** or **onKeyUp**, **onKeyDown** events as per use case

```js
onKeyPress={(event) => {
   if (event.keyCode === '13'){
      console.log('enter key was pressed');      
}}
```

Answer (score 6):

### `keyCode` and `charCode` are Deprecated.

instead use the `key` method to detect the `Enter` key.

```js
onKeyPress={(event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter')
    console.log('Enter Pressed')
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

`onkeypress` event is also deprecated.

I choose to use `onKeyDown` instead of, like this:

```
onKeyDown={(event) => {
   if (event.key === 'Enter')
       console.log('Enter Pressed')
}
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp